# The specified solution configuration "Latest|Any CPU" is invalid

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

I am getting this error with my MSBuild script running in Jenkins

```
C:\<path>\<solutionname>.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution
configuration "Latest|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution 
configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe
Solution.sln
/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank
to use the default solution configuration.
```

In my Jenkins configuration under Build->Command Line Arguments I have

```
/t:Deploy /P:Configuration=Latest
```

I've used this on other projects without any issue before and I've just practically the same build file too but I've never seen this issue happen before.  I suspect that since the only thing that is different is the solution file that there may be something different there that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does the "Latest" configuration exist? By Default Visual Studio creates 2 configurations when you create a new solution. These are "Debug" and "Release" if you want to create a custom configuration you need to use the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio.

Right Click on the Solution in Solution Explorer and select "Configuration Manager" you will then be presented with the following UI. This lists all of the projects in the solution, what type they are (Any CPU, x86 etc) and whether they should be build as part of that configuration.

[image: Visual Studio Configuration Manager UI]

You can now create a configuration called "Latest" and decide what needs to be built for that configuration.

Comment: My issue was forgetting to check in web.config transform for my new configuration.

Comment: in my case - the msbuild was running with the following argument - /p:configuration="default" - but I didn't had the Default configuration added, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to upgrade an ASP.NET Web Forms app from .NET 4.6 to .NET 4.8.

The solution was to download the old Visual Studio Community 2019 version and do the upgrade there. This worked fine. I committed the changes and all was well in Visual Studio 2022 from then on.